# How can I use iTunes with Debian?

Tags: itunes, ipad, unix, wine

Wine fired a lot of errors at least with Ubuntu last time -- and also with Debian, below a picture. Is there any way of using iTunes with *ix -systems? Look I have iPad and I am unable to use it without iTunes -support, example problem [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63282/ipad-good-djvu-reader-with-search-and-easy-uploading-without-itunes).

[image]

Comment: This might also be cross-posted on Ask Ubuntu or even Unix/Linux.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347), running iTunes under Wine is an adventure in itself. Success mainly depends on the specific iTunes version and it might only partially work even then.