# "Cannot connect to iTunes" so cannot install any apps or update them in iPad, why?

Tags: itunes, ipad, ios, ios-appstore

I don't have Mac computer/laptop. I have only iPad. Now I am getting this error `"Cannot connect to iTunes"` although I have never used iTunes. So I cannot install or update any apps in iPad. How can I solve this problem?

Perhaps this is conspiracy but I got the error after I tried to install iTunes to Debian, more [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63283/how-can-i-use-itunes-with-debian), my laptop. My laptop and my iPad are connected to the same wireless Ethernet but they are not linked. Could this cause the malfunctioning of my iPad?

It is very irritating because this error happened totally unexpectedly.

Comment: When is that error showing?

Comment: @Thecafremo the moment I try to install any app or update any app, after succesfully inserting password.

Comment: Try shutting down the Debian running iTunes and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this *Wibbly-Wobbly* solution:

1. Open **Settings** and go to **General / Date & Time**.
2. Tap *Set Automatically* to turn it off.
3. Tap on *Set Date & Time* and enter a date a couple of years in the future.
4. Go out of **Settings**, and back again, and turn on *Set Automatically*. This will restore the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Thecafremo's suggestion did not work the next time I got this bug. I realized that it had to do something with the time, some sort of time-drift in my network, so I **turned off the WIFI and connected to the internet through 3G** -- and it worked!

Some sort of security -validation is based on the time and with heavily-network-reliable devices such as iPad, you seem to get this kind of odd bugs -- not really sure whether some other way exist to solve this, what about without 3G card?